# sample XSD fails with "error: no declaration found for element X"

Tags: c++, xsd, xerces-c, codesynthesis

In spite of being a total newbie in the xml parsing arena, I was able to `xsd` to create valid `c++` and compile and link successfully, but the compiler optimized(?) away the instantiation.  So, starting at step one, I try the [*hello world* xml example at CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2).  But that fails:

```
[wally@lenovotower xml]$ make hello
xsdcxx cxx-tree hello.xsd
g++ -c -o helloschema.o hello.cxx
g++ -g -o hello -lxerces-c helloschema.o hello.c++
[wally@lenovotower xml]$ ./hello
hello.xml:2:8 error: no declaration found for element 'hello'
hello.xml:4:13 error: no declaration found for element 'greeting'
hello.xml:6:9 error: no declaration found for element 'name'
hello.xml:7:9 error: no declaration found for element 'name'
hello.xml:8:9 error: no declaration found for element 'name'
```

hello.c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.hxx"
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
        try {
                auto_ptr<hello_t> h (hello ("hello.xml"));

                for (hello_t::name_const_iterator i (h->name ().begin()); 
                        i != h->name().end();
                        ++i)
                        cout << h->greeting () << ", " << *i << "!" << endl;    
        }
        catch (const xml_schema::exception& e)
        {
                cerr << e << endl;
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

hello.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello>

  <greeting>Hello</greeting>

  <name>sun</name>
  <name>moon</name>
  <name>world</name>

</hello>
```

hello.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

 <xs:complexType name="hello_t">
  <xs:sequence> 
   <xs:element name="greeting" type="xs:string"/>
   <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="hello" type="hello_t"/> 

</xs:schema>
```

I think this is exactly what it says to do, but the commands don't work exactly as documented.  I discovered `xsdcxx` seems to do the right thing (unlike `xsd` which generates C# or vb.net output).

```
[wally@lenovotower xml]$ xsdcxx --version
CodeSynthesis XSD XML Schema to C++ compiler 3.3.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2010 Code Synthesis Tools CC
```

Also, I don't include an `-I`(dir) and it compiles happily.  Could it be using the wrong include file somehow?

What am I doing wrong?  Maybe `xsd` isn't the right tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I find the combination of Python and lxml to be pretty invaluable.  Your XML document and the corresponding XML schema work just fine:

```
from lxml import etree

xsddoc = etree.parse('hello.xsd')
xsd = etree.XMLSchema(xsddoc)
xml_parser = etree.XMLParser(schema=xsd)
xmldoc = etree.parse('hello.xml', parser=xml_parser)
```

I didn't get any errors from that.  I will say, however, that even though lxml doesn't require you to use xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation since it loads the schema you specify, you should still use it as long as you're not using namespaces.  Just because one XML parser is flexible, others might not be, a fact that it seems you might have figured out the hard way.  If you do use namespaces, use xsi:schemaLocation instead of xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation.  Also note that you MUST declare the xsi namespace via the xmlns:xsi attribute to be able to use the xsi:* attributes.

An example using xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation:

```
<hello xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hello.xsd">
  ...
</hello>
```

Comment: How?  What is it you're confused about?

Comment: I am bothered by this, even if it did work (which I have not tried).  The XML my program is going to parse arrives via network from potentially multiple sources:  how could those sources possibly know the schema *path*?

Comment: Ah, that's the problem...  After a quick Google search and a bit of link following, [documentation for validation](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#5.1) turned up.

Comment: I suspect that is a promising lead.  I spent a half hour trying to incorporate the first of that into the test, but I got stubborn compilation problems: *error: no matching function for call to ‘std::auto_ptr<hello_t>::auto_ptr(std::auto_ptr<hello_t>, int, xml_schema::properties&)’*.  The hint about precompiling the schema is the right thing to do; alas it is late, so I'll look into it more tomorrow.  Thanks for the followup!

Comment: This answer led to the proper conclusion which was that `xsd` is far too heavyweight a parser for our use.  I've switched happily and extremely productively to rapidxml instead.  http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

There are some options. The schema location can be provided in the file **hello.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hello.xsd">

  <greeting>Hello</greeting>

  <name>sun</name>
  <name>moon</name>
  <name>world</name>

</hello>
```

Another option is to provide the schema location in the file **hello.c++**

If we assume the schema file is located at the filepath **/some/file/path/hello.xsd**

we should instead of writing

```
auto_ptr<hello_t> h (hello ("hello.xml"));
```

write

```
xml_schema::properties properties;
properties.no_namespace_schema_location("file:///some/file/path/hello.xsd");
auto_ptr<hello_t> h (hello ("hello.xml", 0, properties));
```

You can read more about this in the Codesynthesis FAQ:

[*Why do I get "error: no declaration found for element 'root-element'" when I try to parse a valid XML document?*](http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/Tree/FAQ#Why_do_I_get_.22error%3a_no_declaration_found_for_element_.27root-element.27.22_when_I_try_to_parse_a_valid_XML_document.3F)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Ignore this answer. I'm leaving it up because the comments are worth saving.**

<strike>Your XSD says:</strike>

```
 <xs:complexType name="hello_t">
```

but your XML says:

```
<hello>
...
</hello>
```

Perhaps the XSD should be:

```
 <xs:complexType name="hello">
```

Also, the XML is missing an [xsi:schemaLocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#schemaLocation) declaration. It might help to have one.

Comment: Or xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation since namespaces aren't being used at all.

Comment: I had what the example has, but changing `hello_t` to `hello` in two places in the .xsd causes compilation `error: ‘hello_t’ was not declared in this scope`; changing that also gives a different compile error `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::auto_ptr<hello>::auto_ptr(hello)’`

Comment: @Chrono:  what does that do, and where does that go?

Comment: `<hello xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="hello.xsd">` is what your `<hello>` element should look like.  Whether that will help with xsdcxx is still a mystery until you try it.  :)

Comment: @wallyk: My mistake; I shouldn't have been trying to give XSD advice so late at night (or early in the morning :-) The original XSD is correct as it was. To understand the problem, I think I'd need to look at the generated C++ code, which might or might not be a worthwhile exercise.